# Pytube and the new @ channel urls

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, pytube

I have been working on a python program for a little bit now that can take channel or video urls and convert them into a channel ID.

However my code doesn't seem to work with links that look like "http://youtube.com/@username"

```
if re.search ("/channel/", channelURL) or re.search ("@", channelURL) or re.search ("/user/", channelURL) or re.search ("/c/", channelURL):
                    
                    # This code detects if the given URL is a channel. If the check comes back as True then it grabs the data using pytube.
                
                        
                    c = Channel(channelURL)
                    channel_name = c.channel_name
                    
                    channel_id =  c.channel_id
                    channel_id_link = "http://youtube.com/channel/"+channel_id
                    
                    print("Channel Name: "+channel_name)
                    print("Channel ID: "+channel_id) 
                    print("Channel Link: "+channel_id_link)
```

You can see the full code here. https://github.com/flyinggoatman/YouTube-Link-Extractor/blob/master/QualityYouTube.py

What I expect, the code to be able pull the channel_name, channel_id and also the channel_id_link.

What happens?
The code runs but when I enter in a @ youtube channel URL it returns the following

```
We have logged in as QualityYouTube Bot#2815
Using Discord channel: pending-channels
The bot has now fully booted up and may be used.
Please be advised this bot only supports one Discord server at a time. Future updates will allow for more than one server to be active at a time.
←[30;1m2022-12-30 02:20:50←[0m ←[31mERROR ←[0m ←[35mdiscord.client←[0m Ignoring exception in on_message
←[31mTraceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Users[redacted]\test\QualityYouTube.py", line 101, in on_message
c = Channel(channelURL)
File "C:\Users[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\channel.py", line 24, in init
self.channel_uri = extract.channel_name(url)
File "C:\Users[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 185, in channel_name
raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: channel_name: could not find match for patterns←[0m
```

I understand I don't think the code will run with the current workings. However, can i somehow take the url and use the regex "@(.*)" to grab the username, and then use pytube to find a video made by that channel? I could then take the video URL and use that to get the information I need instead.

Answer (score 0):

Note I fixed the issue by coding new lines of code inside "C:\Users[redacted]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py"

https://github.com/pytube/pytube/pull/1444

I added the following lines of code

```
- :samp:`https://youtube.com/@{channel_name}/*

   r"(?:(@$[%\w\d_-]+)(.*)?)"
```

to this file inside the github for PyTube
https://github.com/pytube/pytube/blob/master/pytube/extract.py

The changes look like this...

```
def channel_name(url: str) -> str:
"""Extract the ``channel_name`` or ``channel_id`` from a YouTube url.

This function supports the following patterns:

- :samp:`https://youtube.com/c/{channel_name}/*`
- :samp:`https://youtube.com/channel/{channel_id}/*
- :samp:`https://youtube.com/u/{channel_name}/*`
- :samp:`https://youtube.com/user/{channel_id}/*
- :samp:`https://youtube.com/@{channel_name}/*`

:param str url:
    A YouTube url containing a channel name.
:rtype: str
:returns:
    YouTube channel name.
"""
patterns = [
    r"(?:\/(c)\/([%\d\w_\-]+)(\/.*)?)",
    r"(?:\/(channel)\/([%\w\d_\-]+)(\/.*)?)",
    r"(?:\/(u)\/([%\d\w_\-]+)(\/.*)?)",
    r"(?:\/(user)\/([%\w\d_\-]+)(\/.*)?)",
    r"(?:\/(@[%\w\d_\-]+)(\/.*)?)"
]
for pattern in patterns:
    regex = re.compile(pattern)
    function_match = regex.search(url)
    if function_match:
        logger.debug("finished regex search, matched: %s", pattern)
        uri_style = function_match.group(1)
        uri_identifier = function_match.group(2)
        return f'/{uri_style}/{uri_identifier}'

raise RegexMatchError(
    caller="channel_name", pattern="patterns"
)
```

PS: the return uri must be of the format `/channelName` because `channel.py` uses (between line@24-29)

```
self.channel_uri = extract.channel_name(url)
self.channel_url = (
    f"https://www.youtube.com{self.channel_uri}"
)
```