# Channel Function in Pytube is not working

Tags: python, pytube

```
from pytube import Channel
c = Channel('https://www.youtube.com/@%s/videos'% channel_name)
for url in c.video_urls:
    print(url)
```

The Code above gives an:

```
RegexMatchError:(raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: channel_name: could not find match for patterns)
```

I tried modifying the extract file like show in [Pytube and the new @ channel urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74957606/pytube-and-the-new-channel-urls), but it didn't work

Comment: @flyinggoatman could you look into it?

Comment: it's a known bug [BUG_RegexMatchError](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1637)